# backtick is not working to run mysql queries in shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, sh

Hi I am trying to run MySQL queries from shell script.

```
mysql -u root -p'1234' -e "CREATE TABLE $DB.aa_vv_cc
(
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
city varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
lat varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`long` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 status int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
);"
```

I am getting error on "long".The back tick is not working from shell script.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As Long is a reserved word in mysql you should not use it as column name.

Comment: Don't know why the hell it's downvoted. Hey arun, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Backticks are `Command Substitution` in the shell.

And they are evaluated in double quoted strings.

So the shell is seeing the

```
`long`
```

in your string and trying to run the command `long` and, presumably, failing.

You need to escape the backticks

```
\`long\`
```

in the double quoted string to prevent that (or use a single quoted string which doesn't evaluate them)

```
'... `long` ...'
```

Comment: This didn't work in my case. I had to use this with Database name like `CREATE TABLE reporting.details AS SELECT * FROM \\`Temp-17-09-19\\`.details;`. But it gave me error **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'Temp-17-09-19.details' doesn't exist**.
So it's considering whole db.tablename as a tablename.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this here i have modify two things `'long'` replace by `\'long\'` and `PRIMARY KEY ('id')` replace by `PRIMARY KEY (id)` this query is work in my shell script.Here the `test` is the name of `database`.

```
mysql -u root  -p'1234' -e "USE test;CREATE TABLE $DB.aa_vv_cc (id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,city varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,lat varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,\`long\`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, status int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-0000:00:00',PRIMARY KEY (id));"
```