# Back-tick inside shell script to execute MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, escaping

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389231/backtick-is-not-working-to-run-mysql-queries-in-shell-script) post seems to be similar but, there, a user points out "long" is a reserved key. So I think even that reserved key is causing some problem, and asking this as new question.

I need to use back-tick inside shell script to execute MySQL query. The database name contains "hyphen" in it. To treat the whole DB name as one I've enclosed it inside back-tick. But shell script uses back-tick for command substitution. So I escaped back-tick with "\". Below is the result.

```
CREATE TABLE reporting.details AS SELECT * FROM \`Temp-17-09-19\`.details;
```

But I'm getting the below error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'Temp-17-09-19.details' doesn't exist

It has considered the whole "db-name.table_name" (Temp-17-09-19.details) as "table" itself. I'm not getting why back-ticks are removed while executing query even after escaping them. Here my context of escaping the back-tick is only from shell script not MySQL query.

Is it doable?

**Update:** As asked by @shellter, below is the full shell script.
And shellter, enclosing the whole query in single quote also giving same error. Also replacing back-tick with single quote is giving MySQL syntax error.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
java -Dtalend.component.manager.m2.repository=$ROOT_PATH/../lib -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/routines.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/activation.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/crypto-utils.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/mail-1.4.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar:$ROOT_PATH/projtablesync_0_1.jar: local.projtablesync_0_1.projTableSync  --context=Default  --context_param Email_To="username@gmail.com" --context_param Email_From="proj@gmail.com" --context_param Email_Cc="user2@gmail.com" --context_param smtp="smtp.gmail.com" --context_param processName="Tag" --context_param dropTempTableQry="drop table if exists reporting.details;" --context_param createTempTableQry="CREATE TABLE reporting.details AS SELECT * FROM \`Temp-17-09-19\`.details;" --context_param updateFinalTableQry="UPDATE  reporting.details AS a  INNER JOIN  reporting.details AS b  ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id AND a.seq_id = b.seq_id SET a.tag_submit_date = b.tag_submit_date, a.tag = b.tag, a.tag_update_date = b.tag_update_date, a.fail_code = b.fail_code, a.is_priority = b.is_priority, a.mobile_platform = b.mobile_platform, a.status = b.status, a.target_countries = b.target_countries, a.content_type = b.content_type, a.status_code = b.status_code, a.status_code_description = b.status_code_description;" --context_param insertFinalTableQry="INSERT INTO reporting.details SELECT a.* FROM reporting.details AS a LEFT JOIN reporting.details AS b ON a.Seq_id = b.Seq_id   AND IFNULL(a.tag_id, \"\") = IFNULL(b.tag_id, \"\") WHERE b.seq_id IS NULL;"
```

Thank you.

Comment: @shellter, I had to delete my previous post. Please reply here.

Comment: Ouch, that is really one **long** cmd. Does something much simpler work, like `SELECT sysdate() from DUAL;` (or the MySQL equivalent)? As I no longer have access to mySQL or any commercial DB, I won't be able to experiment further on your problem. I'd recommend changing your `[shell]` tag to `[bash]` as you'll get many more readers that search for `[bash]` questions. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Ha ha. Actually if you take a close look, there are so many queries. I have problem only here `--context_param createTempTableQry="CREATE TABLE reporting.details AS SELECT * FROM \\`Temp-17-09-19\\`.details;"`. Thank you for suggesting [bash] tag. Will add that too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see how java treats these escape characters and also, '*' is a special character in bash/shell, it also need to be escaped.

You can use single quotes(') instead of double to not escape anything and make shell/bash treat the string as it is (string literal).

Eg:

`` --context_param createTempTableQry='CREATE TABLE reporting.details AS SELECT * FROM `Temp-17-09-19`.details;' ``